# Using 2 5V pins to get 10V

Tags: raspberry-pi, 12v, fan, 5v

I want to to my RaspBerry Pi 4 with an old small CPU fan. However it's a 12V fan. Is it possible to use 2 of the 5V pins on the board to total to 10V? Sorry if this is a dumb question. I haven't worked with electronics in a while.

Comment: Two people walking side by side at 5 km per hour don't easily become one person walking at 10 kph.

Comment: No it is not possible, both of the 5V will not only be referenced to the same ground but also come from the same rail (except for maybe a fuse or diode depending on where you get it from).

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible as the two 5V pins are connected together and both referenced to the same ground potential.

Either you should look for a 5V fan or get a boost dc-dc converter to get to the required voltage.

Comment: I got a [Pimoroni Fan Shim](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/fan-shim) for my Pi 4. 9.60 UK pounds. Idles at 34 - 36 C.